# Mybatis how to run the sql "desc table"

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I have a promble about how to run the sql "desc table" to get table fields info.

I am try run this those code to get table fields info, but got an syntax error.

```
@Mapper
public interface TableMapper {

/**
 * 获取指定表中字段的具体信息
 * @param tableName 表名
 * @return 所有字段的具体信息.
 */
@Select("desc #{tableName}")
@Results({
        @Result(property = "fieldName", column = "Field", javaType = String.class),
        @Result(property = "fieldType", column = "Type", javaType = String.class),
        @Result(property = "nullable", column = "Null", javaType = String.class),
        @Result(property = "key", column = "Key", javaType = String.class),
        @Result(property = "extra", column = "Extra", javaType = String.class)
})
Set<TableFieldInfo> findTableFieldsInfo(@Param(value = "tableName") String tableName);}
```

Can some one tell me how to get table fields info with mybaits?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow, to make it easier for other developers to help you it's better to copy the code here instead of screenshots.

Comment: Thank you remind me. In the future i will do it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
desc #{tableName}
     ^
```

to

```
desc ${tableName}
     ^
```

Comment: 遺漏中國人的角色 (leave out the chinese chars)

Comment: "what's wrong with you?"  @Himly Nothing i know off ... But stackoverflow.com is a english only speaking website..

Comment: Got it. I am a new, sorry about that.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I mistaken what your meant,  My english not so good. Sorry about that.

Comment: @lucumt I mistaken what his meant.

Comment: @Himly, he said stackoverflow is English only,we should avoid use Chinese,I have remove it,now stop keeping focus on this and continue to do your work or go to sleep